# Open "Inspect Element" window via JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

Is there a function or method for prompting the Developer Tools console to open using JavaScript? I.e. click on something on a page and it will pop up. I'm assuming "no" since I failed to find it, but hopefully it is possible.

Comment: No, that's not possible. the quickest way to launch the DevTool's console is by pressing F12. Programatically, afaik it's not possible to launch the dev tools for an arbitrary page. I've found a method to launch the dev tools for an extension page though.

Comment: @RobW Since this is in an extension: could you direct me to the method for doing that?

Comment: The method only works for opening dev tools instanes for eg the background page of any extension. I'm not sharing the method, because the application is probably not intended by the Chromium developers, and possibly removed once publicly known. What's wrong with the F12 method? What you're looking for might be achieveable in a different way.

Comment: I wanted it to be possible to use Chrome's built-in color manager (when you click on a color in the Dev Tools). It isn't necessary for my extension to waste space with additional code to make my own or use a third party color picker. So I was hoping to launch the Dev Tools on click.

Comment: That's a horrible reason for wanting to launch the dev tools. Several freely available color picker libraries do already exist. If you reslly like Webkit's color picker, just have a look at its source code. If you don't want to waste space on color picker libs, use the `<input type="color">` element.

Comment: I've used nearly every type of HTML5 input for some reason or another, but I never noticed that one. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Next time, you'd better ask that directly ;) See this meta topic: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I was still entirely interested in doing what this question asked, which is why I've left it up. The only thing I wish the color input had would be transparency, but I can implement that through other means.

Comment: Here's a link to the color picker used in Chrome before it was put in Chrome.... http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/Bu6sn/  ....  heres a link to the thread were he talks about it... https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/TdHoU7gFFyc

Comment: These comments reminded me of: https://xkcd.com/1172/

Answer (score -1):

No, it is not possible to do so, for the same reason that it is not possible to use JavaScript in a web-page to access files from your local computer. Allowing a web-page direct access to the browser functions would be a security problem.

Comment: Right answer.. Bad reasoning, though. There are plenty of browser "functions" accessible via APIs by web pages.

Comment: If you go to iCloud.com, open a photo, right click, then you will see a custom context menu, and there is a custom inspect button that opens the inspector

Comment: responding to a right-click is more secure than directly triggering the action with javascript.

uploading a file in response to you *choosing one* manually is more secure than directly uploading the file behind the scenes without the user knowing.

browsers have security feature that will allow some actions in response to a *manual directive* triggering it, but disallow those same actions if there is no manual action involved.